# Why does lxqt-build-tools fail to build?

Tags: compiling, cmake, lxqt

I would like to build `LxQt` from sources on a `Ubuntu xenial` derivative system. I followed the oder as described on https://github.com/lxde/lxqt/wiki/Building-from-source and `libqtxdg` compiled and installed fine but the second piece `lxqt-build-tools` doesn't run through cmake. I've installed all the listed Ubuntu pre requisites but I get the following for the mentioned package:

```
$ cmake ../
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works          
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info                                
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done                         
-- Detecting CXX compile features                                 
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done                          
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1")  
-- Checking for module 'glib-2.0>=2.50'                           
--                                                                
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:367 (message):                                                      
  A required package was not found                                
Call Stack (most recent call first):                              
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:532 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (pkg_check_modules)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ron/src/lxqt/lxqt-build-tools/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
ron@ron-notebook:~/src/lxqt/lxqt-build-tools/build$
```

and I can't tell what went wrong. The listed log file does not provide much information either.... How do I get past this?

Comment: Your glib is older than 2.50. I think this is more than enough information.

Comment: @IporSircer but it says `Checking for module 'glib-2.0>=2.50' ` hence I assume that anything inbetween 2.0 and 2.50 should be okay, am I misunderstanding this? I have `glibc-2.0` installed

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: You need the package `libglib2.0-dev` with a version no less than 2.5 to work.

**Long answer** (see also the comments to the original post):

`glib-2.0` is the name to refer the package in `pkgconfig` and other tools. `glib-2.0` does not necessarily mean the version number is `2.0`. Since you are compiling from source. It is very likely that what you really need is `libglib2.0-dev` with a version not less than `2.5`. `dev` here means "development" and you may interpret it as "you'll need this if you want to build something yourself". You need a development package to do compilation. Keep this in mind when compiling from source in the future. It will save your time.

Comment: Yes, Xenial only has [`libglib2.0-dev` version 2.48](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0).

Comment: I suggest you either build `glib` from source, or compromise and use a slightly lower version of `LxQt` which accepts 2.48. The second choice is much simpler, actually. Ubuntu does have 2.54, however.